# Can conjured creatures bring back something (objects or creatures)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning

Can a [conjured](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) creature (e.g., called, summoned or created) bring back something when returning to the original plane?

Examples could be an object a willing creature or an unwilling grappled creature.

I would guess *no*, but I did not find anything about it in the rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between [the three subtypes of conjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) you mention.

> Conjurations transport creatures from another plane of existence to your plane (calling); create objects or effects on the spot (creation); heal (healing); bring manifestations of objects, creatures, or forms of energy to you (summoning); or transport creatures or objects over great distances (teleportation).

1. Summoning - these can't bring something with them, they are only a quasi-real "manifestation" in the first place. When they leave all their spells expire, they can't summon, they "re-form" when killed, etc. For example, summoners' eidolons can't take gear with them when they are dismissed. So if you give your Summoned Monster a sword, it goes "clang" on the floor when they depart.
2. Creation - these are created, they don't "come from" anywhere. So there's nowhere to take something back to. When they disappear it is "unto dust you shall return."  Phantom steeds and black tentacles just "go away," they don't go somewhere. So it's the same "clang on the floor."
3. Calling - here you honest-to-God gate in a specific real creature from another plane. They can take things in with them and can take something you give them back with them. Planar Ally and Planar Bindings are pretty much just a real creature stopping by for a visit, they can do whatever they want/you force them to. If you tell them "take this sword to the 333rd layer of the Abyss!" then they'll do it. (They may or may not have it when you call them again, your binding is only in effect while called, so if they don't like you they may have sold it at the Dis Pawn Shop or something.)

Comment: And what if a summoned creature swallowed another creature? When the first disappear, will the swallowed just "reappear"?

Comment: Yes, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't mention anything about the creature being allowed to take things back, I would agree with your assessment that **no**, you cannot take anything back to your plane of origin when the spell/effect ends. Only the things you brough with you are returned.